# SQL Server: how can I change this query to use subquery with date column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I have a query that has about 20 columns, for brevity I'm showing `*`

```
SELECT TOP 1
    *
FROM 
    [Frontier].[dbo].[tblLoadFile]
WHERE
    TN = 4132644856
ORDER BY 
    CallTime DESC
```

I am told that I should use a `max` on `calldate` in a `subquery` as it is the "faster" and "proper" way to write the query.

How and where would I put in a `max(calldate)` subquery?

This is for SQL Server / T-SQL

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this query?  Return the most recent `CallTime`? Return all the columns that are associated with the most recent `CallTime`?

Comment: Don't remove important details for brevity.  You're specifically asking about doing a `Max()` function on a column, but cutting out the entire column structure of your `SELECT`.  Show the full query.

Comment: Sounds like someone suggested you replace the `Top 1` with `max(calldate)`. But you will also need a GROUP BY if you are using MAX as it is an aggregate function (@ollie is asking the same question in a different way. Basically do you need 1 column, or 20 columns because that will change the query.

Comment: Do you mean "use max(calldate) instead of TOP 1 order by callTime"?   If so, I don't think that's faster or proper.

Comment: Also, please explain what you're trying to accomplish.  Show some sample data and a desired result.  Simply stating that you were told something is faster and asking how to implement it doesn't tell us what you're trying to do.  It might be faster, it might not.  We don't have crystal balls, you need to explain what you're doing.

Comment: @TabAlleman well using max will almost certainly be faster than an order by, but the issue is aggregation.

Comment: @JacobH Depends how the table is indexed.   Also using MAX() could result in more than one row if there is a tie.

Comment: Any examples in an answer?   Yes ... replace Top1 and others is what i'm told

Comment: If there's a tie then will display 2 rows is this what you want?

Comment: No,  never wanting 2 records

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not trying to change the logic of your current query, the way you would replace TOP 1/Order by with a MAX subquery would be something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Frontier].[dbo].[tblLoadFile]
where TN = 4132644856
AND CallTime = (SELECT MAX(CallTime) 
                FROM  [Frontier].[dbo].[tblLoadFile]
                where TN = 4132644856)
```

However, as I mentioned in comments, this could produce more than one row if there is a tie, and it isn't necessarily faster, depending on how the table is indexed.

Comment: I get 2 records from that ,

Comment: Ughh,  there are identical  CallTime  `2017-01-17 14:05:57.000`

Comment: Like I said.   : )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider without using MAX, and guaranteed one row back.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CallTime DESC) AS Rownum
        FROM [Frontier].[dbo].[tblLoadFile]
        WHERE TN = 4132644856
) a
WHERE a.Rownum = 1
```